# React state variables are sometimes empty

Tags: reactjs, redux, null, state, react-props

I'm at the beginning of my project with React and before i ask want to say its just my hobby :)
im building my own small site for educational support and i have now an issue and i cant explain it why it is not working

here is my full code of an edit page of some masterData:

```
    const FormHelperBoxType = ({
      auth,
      dataToEdit: { dataContent, imageLink },

      setDataToEdit,
      setimageLink,
      saveImageToObject,
      dataClear,
    }) => {
      const url = clientConfig.backendHOST + '/api/masterData';
      const urlEnd = '/HelperBoxType';
      const dataSource = createStore({
        API data source for DevExpress component works fine.
      });

  var myWidget = window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
    {
      //cloudinary authentication
    },
    (error, result) => {
      if (!error && result && result.event === 'success') {
        console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info);
        
        setimageLink(result.info);
      }
    }
  );

    return <Button text='Test' onClick={buttonClick} />;
      );

      const renderButton = function (props) {
        function buttonClick(e) {
          setDataToEdit(props.data);
          myWidget.open();
        }

        return <Button text='Test' onClick={buttonClick} />;
      };

      const onSaving = React.useCallback((e) => {
        console.log(dataContent, imageLink);
        var updData = {
          helperboxTypeId: dataContent.helperboxTypeId,
          image: imageLink.secure_url,
        };

        const body = JSON.stringify(updData);
        console.log('data sent to API', updData);
        saveImageToObject(updData, url + urlEnd);
      }, []);

  
      return (
        <Fragment>
          // data grid from DevExpress works fine
        </Fragment>
      );
    };

    FormHelperBoxType.propTypes = {
      auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      dataToEdit: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

      setDataToEdit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      dataClear: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      setimageLink: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      saveImageToObject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      auth: state.auth,
      dataToEdit: state.dataToEdit,
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
      setDataToEdit,
      dataClear,
      setimageLink,
      saveImageToObject,
    })(withRouter(FormHelperBoxType));
```

My problem is that i need to extend the default save method of DevExpress GRid controller which is done in **onSaving**. Before that on the editPopup i have a button for the widget. By pressing this button i store the row i edited into **dataToEdit** (the whole record). If the upload of the image was fine then i store the public link of the image into **imageLink**
In the redux developer console i see the values they are set correctly.
And now starts the funny thing... in 30% of the cases it works properly, but in the most cases i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helperboxTypeId' of null
```

This happens in the onSaving method when i assign to the updData:

```
     var updData = {
      helperboxTypeId: dataContent.helperboxTypeId,
      image: imageLink.secure_url,
    };
```

if i put a *console.log(dataContent, imageLink);* before then it helps and works...

what is what i dont get? or what is the mistake i did? :)
(The reducer and so on is working i can see the values properly in the devTools.)

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the version of ES which you are using.

**First Idea:** (It can fail based on your environment)

One change from the previous year is the optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```js
var updData = {
  helperboxTypeId: dataContent?.helperboxTypeId,
  image: imageLink?.secure_url,
};
```

**Second Idea:**

You can set default values (Empty objects. So, it won't break your run). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
const FormHelperBoxType = ({
  auth,
  dataToEdit: { dataContent = {}, imageLink = {} },
  setDataToEdit,
  setimageLink,
  saveImageToObject,
  dataClear,
}) => {
```

Comment: Let me know if this works for you @Ernő László

Comment: hi yes the default value worked and this avoid to get an error and the page doesn’t collapse. but the save mechanism is not solved. of course i can always put it to console.log but I’m not sure its a really good idea. :) im sure that i overseen something small thing.

Comment: i cant give you points im too new here :D

Comment: Which is the error with the save mechanism? Can you give me more context?

Comment: that the values are often empty. now the page doesn’t crash but still not saving. i have to try to save the values somewhere else.... as a local variable maybe.

Comment: I had to read a lot your code to try to understand what was happening. Can you remove the `React.useCallback` from `onSaving` definition? and try it again? It'd be something like: `const onSaving = (e) => { ....` (Also remember to delete the `, [])` at the end of the definition of the `onSaving`)

Comment: Hi still the same effect... so i made a workaround and put the values to localstore... but its not a real and beaty solution